# Can ContactPoint markup be made with Microdata or only JSON?

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org

I read this question, [How to define phone types using Schema.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248212/how-to-define-phone-types-home-office-work-using-schema-org), but it uses JSON. And then [Google's Instructions for Corporate Contacts](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/customize/contact-points) uses JSON and finally [Schema.org Contactpoint](https://schema.org/ContactPoint) only shows examples in JSON.

Does this not exist without JSON? I'm not pulling from a database or anything so don't really want to use unnecessary JSON code.

Currently my Contact stuff is like this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/LocalBusiness'>
<p><strong>Contact Us:</strong></p>
    <p>
        Toll free: <strong itemprop='telephone'>1-800-123-4567</strong><br>
        Local: 1-407-123-4567<br>
        Email: <span itemprop='email'>info@company-name.com</span>
    </p>
```

Is there a way to add the required `@type='ContactPoint'` and `contactType='customer service'` to the HTML markup instead of needing to add JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Microdata (as you do in your example) as well.  Just add the necessary properties and missing data (with a `meta` tag) for example like this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/LocalBusiness'>
    <p><strong>Contact Us:</strong></p>
    <p itemprop='contactPoint' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/ContactPoint'>
        <meta itemprop='contactType' content='customer service'>
        Toll free: <strong itemprop='telephone'>+1-800-123-4567</strong><br>
        Local: 1-407-123-4567<br>
        Email: <span itemprop='email'>info@company-name.com</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: So itemprop is in place of @type?

Comment: No, itemtype corresponds to @type, itemprop corresponds to the property in JSON-LD. Please note that properties and types are case-sensitive.